# What are the Analog to TTL serial ICs called?

Tags: sensor, bluetooth

I have a sensor that measures an analog value and i want a ICs to convert it to TTL serial ,

because i want to send it afterwards via a bluetooth IC that takes TTL serial as input. I already  have a working prototype with a µController but i want something more compact and doesn't need to be programmed.
What are the keywords that i should use form my research?
thank you

Comment: Well you have to have a protocol over the rs232 line, that both ends speak. You can for example use a microcontroller that has both adc pins and rs232 interface onboard and write a program that translates the analogue input to whatever protocol you choose over rs232

Comment: Probably no such thing that I've heard of, but depending on requirements and volume you can probably get something like a PIC10F220 factory programmed for under 50 cents in a SOT-23-6 package.

Comment: Of course that's in 1ku or higher quantities for that price,  I'm assuming

Comment: yes in 1ku or higher quantities

Comment: Also, does the bluetooth take actual rs232 Or does it take ttl level serial

Comment: Actually i just realized it's TTL not RS232

Comment: I think you need to combine the use of an ADC and a microcontroller to do the conversion for you. I am not aware of any devices that has all of this functionality built-in.

You can buy very compact microcontrollers in surface mount (SMD or SMT) packages. I would start there.

What microcontroller are you using in your prototype?

Comment: i found it ! texas instr's Cc2540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Such ICs Are Called As**

**Analog To Digital Converters**

Once your sensor measures the analog signal you need to convert analog signal to digital format and then transmit via Bluetooth since it operates with TTL(Digital) signals whose levels are typically 5V range.

Transistor–transistor logic (TTL) is a class of digital circuits built from bipolar junction transistors (BJT) and resistors.(Source WIKI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic)